# tkinter canvas item configure

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make a dice object, and I want to be able to control the pip colors. I created the pips with a black fill, and I tried to change one to red using

```
self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.pip1, fill='red')
```

but it seems to have no effect.  There is no error so I'm wondering why the change doesn't show up.

Minimum working example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Dice:
    #the x and y instancing variables are for the x and y coordinates of the top left corner of the rectangle
    def __init__(self, win, x, y):
        self.win = win
        self.win.geometry("500x500")
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.win)
        self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)

        die = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+88, y+88, fill='white', width=1)
        offset = 20

        #create 7 circles for pip locations:

        self.pip1 = self.pips(x+offset, y+offset)
        self.pip2 = self.pips(x+offset, y+2*offset)
        self.pip3 = self.pips(x+offset, y+3*offset)
        self.pip4 = self.pips(x+2*offset, y+2*offset)
        self.pip5 = self.pips(x+3*offset, y+offset)
        self.pip6 = self.pips(x+3*offset, y+2*offset)
        self.pip7 = self.pips(x+3*offset, y+3*offset)

        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.pip1, fill='red')

    def pips(self, x, y):
        pip = self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+9, y+9, fill='black', width=0)

    #def setValue(self, value)

    #def pipsOff(self, pip):



def test():
    x = Dice(Tk(), 50, 50)
    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule of debugging: examine your data. If you put a print statement or stop the debugger just before the call to `itemconfigure` you will see that `self.pip1` has a value of `None`. So the first thing you should ask yourself is, "why is it `None`?"

The reason it is `None` is that you create it in a method but neglect to return the item id. So, the fix to your problem is to add `return pip` at the end of the function `pips`:

```
def pips(self, x, y):
    pip = self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+9, y+9, fill='black', width=0)
    return pip
```

Comment: Yep...that does the trick.  But what I don't understand is that even without the return statement in the pips function, the original black pips were still drawn.  Can you explain why that might be?

Comment: @sq1020: it's because the function created the pips just fine. You were simply not returning their name to the calling function.