# Clear canvas in Tkinter without deleting everything

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm quite new to tkinter (by new i mean I picked it up 2 hours ago) and so there is probably a really simple solution to this I'm just not seeing. But I want to clear a canvas so that I can redraw it. But I don't want to use delete as I then change the ID# of all the items as I redraw them. Is there a way to clear the canvas that retains the ID# of my items?

Thanks

I'm programing in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Better yet, if there was a way to simply redraw the canvas. Clearing it is really just half the way there. I want to redraw the window after moving a frame around and maintain all of me objects IDs.

Comment: Why do you think you need to redraw anything? If you "move a frame around" the canvas will redraw itself. Are you seeing a specific behavior that you don't like?

Comment: I want to move a frame, and several ovals that i draw around it and several arcs that i draw between multiple frames.

Comment: Ok, So i see now that there is a move function, that lets with things like the ovals and the frames. but only 1 of the points where my arcs attach are changing when I move a frame. (arcs connect the frames) Is there a function to configure canvas items just like you can configure other widgets so that I can change these values as I need?

Comment: hey look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179630/tkinter-canvas-item-configure

Comment: did i mention I just learned it 2 hours before I got this far? xD

Answer (score 0):

So. It isn't clearing and redrawing that I want. it is the ability to move and configure items. The functions for which are:

```
Canvas.configureItem(TAGORID,OPTION=VALUE)
```

and

```
Canvas.move(TAGORID,distanceToMoveX,distanceToMoveY)
```

thanks for your insight Bryan. That was just the kick in the right direction I needed to figure it out.

To find out what the options are for configItem, call it with only a tag or an ID, it will return the appropriate options. for example, options for an oval are:

- stipple
- disabledoutlinestipple
- activeoutlinestipple
- dash
- disabledwidth
- dashoffset
- activewidth
- fill
- disabledoutline
- offset
- disabledfill
- disableddash
- width
- state
- outlinestipple
- disabledstipple
- activedash
- tags
- activestipple
- activeoutline
- outlineoffset
- activefill
- outline